# Delete only the line following the regex while retaining the line with the regex

Tags: sed

Ok, I'm completely stumped...

Scenario: An .rtf file with 100 lines of text when viewed with Word.  The word "Linux" on one line with a blank line below it.  I need to retain the line with "Linux" and remove the blank line below it.  However, the line isn't truly blank when looking at it with vi, so none of the posts dealing with removing a blank line don't work.  Also, I can find plenty of posts to remove the line with the regex AND the next line, but I need to keep the regex line.  There is only one line in the file with the word "Linux".

I know sed can do this, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/Linux/{n;d;}'
```

(...And an Answer must contain at least 30 characters.)

Comment: Maybe change to `sed '/^Linux$/{n;d;}'  thefile > thenewfile`  (if Linux is really the only thing on the relevant line)... but your solution's idea stays correct.

Comment: @OlivierDulac: I thought of that, but *'"There is only one line in the file with the word "Linux"'*.

Comment: Thanks Olivier and Beta!  I've tried that, and it appears to work on CentOS, but for some reason, Word won't open the file (says it's corrupt).  I've been trying with gnuwin sed installed on a Windows 7 machine, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Word doesn't play well with others; if Word wrote the file to begin with, it might not tolerate editing by other tools.

Comment: You got it, Beta!  All the hidden characters don't play well at all.  Going down a different path.  I do appreciate both of you with the Quick assist!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? I had a look at an RTF file, it looked as if there were carriage returns separating the lines. So I used those as record separators and removed one line and and was able to read the resulting file and the line was gone. I have no idea if it would work in other situations. You'd have to test thoroughly if it works. I used awk, since rtf files are not "valid" text files in Unix/Linux, and I think probably `sed` cannot do it..

```
awk 'n-->0{next} /Linux/{n=1}1' RS='\r' ORS='\r' infile.rtf > outfile.rtf
```

If it works it should discard the line below the line with the word "Linux".

Comment: Scrutinizer,  No joy with awk either.  I'm guessing due to the .rtf characters, neither will work.  I do appreciate the assist!

Comment: Oh, well it was worth a try.. ;) The rtf I used was created using MS Word, perhaps that makes a difference..